Can permutation polynomials generate any permutation?
I struggle with permutation polynomials, that I want to use as random permutations in {0,... n-1}, with some seeding parameter s (scalar ou vector) to change the permutation.
For a start,

Is the generative space of s for a given permutation polynomial reaching all the possible permutations(n) under some conditions, or is it always only a small subset ?
E.g. for n = 4 = 2², ( 2x² + x +c ) %4 ( = case Z/p^kZ ), gives a generative space of size only 4 ( {0,3,2,1} + rolls ), which is too poor. But would another polynomial get them all ? Or could it be possible only for some other set sizes ?
( BTW, why is 2x² + x not listed in the "all polynomials of degree <=5" section ? )

